# React correctly assigning function to property then using inside child component

Tags: reactjs, function, properties

I'm making a hangman game something like this:
[image]

Letters.js

```
import React from 'react';
import AvailableLetter from './AvailableLetter/AvailableLetter';

const letters = (props) => {
    const playHandler = (alphabet) => {
        const solution = props.solution.split('');
        console.log(solution);

        if (solution.indexOf(alphabet)<0)
        {
            console.log('incorrect');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('correct');
            return true;
        }
    }

    const availableLetters = [ ...props.feed ].map(
        (alphabet,i) => {
            return (
                <AvailableLetter play={()=>{playHandler(alphabet)}} correct={()=>{props.correct(alphabet)}} incorrect={()=>{props.incorrect(alphabet)}} solution={props.solution} key={i} alphabet={alphabet} />
            );
        }
    );

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Game</h1>
            <p>Solution: {props.solution}</p>
            {availableLetters}
        </div>
    );
}

export default letters;
```

AvailableLetter.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import classes from './AvailableLetter.module.css';

const AvailableLetter = (props) => {
    const [show,setShow]=useState(true);
    // const [clicked, setClicked]=useState(false);
    // const [outcome,setOutcome]=useState(false);

    // if (show)
    // {
    //     setClicked(true);
    // }

    // const play = (alphabet) => {
    //     const solution = props.solution.split('');
    //     if (solution.indexOf(alphabet)<0)
    //     {
    //         return false;
    //     }
    //     else
    //     {
    //         return true;
    //     }
    // }

    if (!show)
    {
        if (props.play())
        {
            //props.correct();
            alert('correct');
        }
        else
        {
            //props.incorrect();
            alert('wrong');
        }
    }

    const letter = show ? <span onClick={()=>{setShow(false)}} className={classes.AvailableLetter}>{props.alphabet}</span> : null;

    return (
        <span>
            {letter}
        </span>
    );
}

export default AvailableLetter;
```

When I click on any letter I get alerted 'wrong' for any letter even though logic inside playHandler seems correct. In this case solution is set as 'apple'.

I want to check with you guys whether I am calling props.play() correct from inside AvailableLetter.js.

From Letters.js:

```
const playHandler = (alphabet) => {
        const solution = props.solution.split('');
        console.log(solution);

        if (solution.indexOf(alphabet)<0)
        {
            console.log('incorrect');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('correct');
            return true;
        }
    }

...

const availableLetters = [ ...props.feed ].map(
        (alphabet,i) => {
            return (
                <AvailableLetter play={()=>{playHandler(alphabet)}} correct={()=>{props.correct(alphabet)}} incorrect={()=>{props.incorrect(alphabet)}} solution={props.solution} key={i} alphabet={alphabet} />
            );
        }
    );
```

From AvailableLetters:

```
if (!show)
    {
        if (props.play())
        {
            //props.correct();
            alert('correct');
        }
        else
        {
            //props.incorrect();
            alert('wrong');
        }
    }
```

Have I assigned

```
play={()=>{playHandler(alphabet)}}
```

correctly?

Also calling

```
props.play()
```

Is this correct?

THanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `play={()=>{playHandler(alphabet)}}` will do what you expect - it calls `playHandler(alphabet)` but doesn't do anything with the result. In AvailableLetters, `props.play()` will always return `undefined`

Change it to one of these:

`play={() => { return playHandler(alphabet) }}`

or the shorter form:

`play={() => playHandler(alphabet)}`

Comment: changd onClick={()=>setShow(false)} inside AvailableLetter now i think works.